# What are the various block size increase proposals?

Tags: block, blocksize, block-size-increase

I'm aware of BIP101 and BIP100, but I'm sure there are others. I would like a simple table of comparison on the block size increase schedule of each one (including the status quo) in one place.

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/40470/what-is-bitcoin-core-developers-solution-to-the-increasing-number-of-transaction/40472#40472